# Event maps and type guards

Tags: typescript

Let's say I'm building an event manager for a chat app.
I've used event maps before and had a good time with it, so I will try it again.

This is the event map:

```js
interface ChatEventMap {
    incomingMessage: string;
    newUser: {
        name: string;
        id: number;
    };
}

type EvType = keyof ChatEventMap;
type Ev<T extends EvType> = ChatEventMap[T];
```

So, to listen to an event, we have an `on` function that receives two args: the `type` (or name) of the event, and a callback that is called passing the event data.

It's something like this:

```js
function on<T extends EvType>(type: T, callback: (data: Ev<T>) => void) {
    // do stuff
}

on('newUser', user => {
    console.log(user.name); // No errors!
});
```

But now I have the need to listen to ALL events at once. I thought of making an `onEvent` function that receives only a callback with the event type and it's data.

The problem is that inside the callback function, type guard is not working!

```js
function onEvent(callback: <T extends EvType>(
    ev: { type: T; data: ChatEventMap[T] },
) => void) {
    // do stuff
}

onEvent(ev => {
    if (ev.type === 'newUser') {
        console.log(ev.data.name); // Error: Property 'name' does not exist on type 'ChatEventMap[T]'
    }
});
```

What am I doing wrong?

[TS Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgMIAs5gKIDcLgCycADsgN4CwAUMncqAgPYC2oA5oRAM7dzsQAXMm5goHANw16yEBADuAVW7RhVWjPrAAJsJABXFgCNoUjZtlwWQkWMnT6AXzOOaNMAE8SKPABUvKAC8yADWEB5MMGiYOPhEpGae3sh4ADy%20yBAAHpAg2twpuP7eAHzIwRhYeARgxCQA2r4AumZu1DQw%20iAIYMBMIMj96Zk5BPmFxRAlABRJNr4ANMgIcAA2q0aIIcLT2lhwwmm%20JQCU5WW4TDpn6jIA9HfI2ky2%20jAwNK7t1P3TAORyJQqKB-Jb6YHnCgOOjMEDcJirCAAOlWTHY03B0CRICsEBOEmQD2QADkXtAoEwoNwAISffFtBnUTrdXr9QYgargaYrdabBDbZDDbK5cZ%20AIzaGZXBqZBzYS%20Al7MAHaJVOK1UiNJrIRwLGhnQIXK7aG6SonPV7vT5tfqcsDTCC4SG3LRRB24JFzcqBYIAhTKaB-U3mTSw%20GIlFo91IpVwbG4-GEx7YKAUqDCAAKFO8UE8yABuL%20TyYPFkTDAI2AonZsoC%20cqsRqdS1f0lX0c9OoQA)

Comment: so you want to make a middleware where when there a message, all function will be called?

Comment: @Julio Hintze please let me know if it is helpful https://catchts.com/publish-subscribe
If yes, I will answer your question

Comment: @captain-yossarian, this page only covers the "specific event" listener (the "on" function that I wrote does this already) it seems, so I still need the "onEvent" function (the function that will call a callback for EVERY event triggered). That being said, this page's solution is very interesting. Maybe if I play with it a little I can find the answer, but it is not very obvious to me right now.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here you have working code

```js
interface ChatEventMap {
  incomingMessage: string;
  newUser: {
    id: number;
    name: string;
  };
}

type EvType = keyof ChatEventMap;
type Ev<T extends EvType> = ChatEventMap[T];

// a bit of love for TypeScript
type Mapped = {
  [P in keyof ChatEventMap]: {
    type: P, data: ChatEventMap[P]
  }
}


function on<T extends EvType>(type: T, callback: (data: Ev<T>) => void) {
  // do stuff
}

on('newUser', user => {
  console.log(user.name); // No errors!
});

function onEvent(callback: (ev: Mapped[EvType]) => void) { }

onEvent(ev => {
  if (ev.type === 'newUser') {
    console.log(ev.data.name); // ok
  }
  if (ev.type === 'incomingMessage') {
    console.log(ev.data); // ok, string
  }
});
```

Sometimes, generics are not the best solution.

Please keep in mind, that next two functions are not  the same:

```js
function onEvent(callback: <T extends EvType>(ev: Mapped[T]) => void) { }

function onEvent(callback: (ev: Mapped[EvType]) => void) { }
```

Comment: Mapping the `ChatEventMap` to a union of all possible event objects like you have done here is definitely what I would do.  The reason that the original doesn't work is that `T` could be broader than just a single string key.  You could have `T` be the union `incomingMessage | newUser`.  For that reason, checking `ev.type === 'newUser'` refines the variable `ev.type` but it does not refine `T`.  If `T` is a union, then you could have a `type` and a `data` that don't match.  We want to enforce that they always match, so your `Mapped[EvType]` achieves that.

Comment: So simple! Looks like I have some studying to do, and this answer and @LindaPaiste amazing comment above will surely be my starting point.

Comment: @LindaPaiste thanks for comment. It is impossible to say better than you

Comment: @LindaPaiste is there a name for this approach? I've been struggling with some typesafe event registration and this _seems_ like it makes sense, but can't quite intuit why (yet!).

Comment: @mdhvn please provide an example of code that you are struggling with

Comment: It's a little tricky in a comment, but I essentially would like the type safety that's provided by this mapping, but then I want to store some map, or `Record` of `event -> callback`. 

So I want essentially the same `on` method, but then to store the provided callback (in, say, a class field). 

`on(event: Event, cb: CallBack) { this.callbacks[event] = cb }` kind of thing.

The context is that the class will register for postMessage events, and call a registered event callback when necessary.

Comment: @mdhvn The broader concept here is [mapped types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/mapped-types.html) (the `type Mapped`) with [indexed access types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/indexed-access-types.html) (`Mapped[EvType]`) to create a [union type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#union-types) of the values.  But as a specific "design pattern" I don't know if there's an "official" name for it?  I think of it as the "union of valid pairs" approach.

Comment: The type that we create here, `Mapped[EvType]`, is called a [discriminated union](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/narrowing.html#discriminated-unions) ([the old docs are also good](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/unions-and-intersections.html#discriminating-unions)). *"When every type in a union contains a common property with literal types, TypeScript considers that to be a discriminated union, and can narrow out the members of the union."* See also: [narrowing](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/narrowing.html)

Comment: The `type` property of the `ev` object is a [string literal type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#literal-types).  In this example it is a union of two literal values: `'incomingMessage' | 'newUser'`.  Once TypeScript knows that `ev.type` is the literal string `'newUser'` it can narrow the types of the other properties accordingly.

Comment: @mdhvn [Here is quite a lot of code to address your issue.](https://tsplay.dev/w656rW)

Comment: Wow, thanks a lot for all of this, very much appreciated. I'm familiar with both literal unions and discriminated unions, but I think I need to develop my intuition a bit when they're all combined with indexed/mapped types. This is really helpful!

Answer (score 0):

You can simply do:

```
type EventCallback = <T extends keyof ChatEventMap>(event: { type: T, data: ChatEventMap[T]}) => void

function onEvent(callback: EventCallback) {
  // Do stuff
}
```

Comment: In theory it would work, right? But in reality type guard inside the callback function does not work. I will update the question to clarify.

Answer (score 0):

I played a bit with your problem.

[Here is what I came up with.](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#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-t7UwDQeDIdCQLCGujCcTSQhych0RBcMIMPVynSKhGmUq2RzleZkDztHzRAKhdQRdQwRCoTDgNwrQplNAq31wPn4g1K3Oa1GPEzhAhF34GKUpw0MpLxzLxTUufQoBAwPooDn19W-Nq5qEQmF99LoOLhe6B1nh6OD5ON+AABMtZDEixSlKi1Szre4ALjBYAgQyjJrgBYBbr0u4vhOsrHiqyBnheV4Eqh949E+z5Sth769u6rx5uWSonnQwCxGWuCkWk5HIFhh6cnhMjltqVJwCaZp4TsMgsaWI5jq+UA7uUbGMnxrYCexcz8fQaoalqur6mxQmrKJ1gWsg4mumYQA)

You can see I tried to implement an explicit type guard. The first one works with any:

```
function isNewUserChatEvent(chatEvent: ChatEvent<any>): chatEvent is ChatEvent<'newUser'> {
    return chatEvent.type === 'newUser'
}
```

But the second one doesn't work and, I think, is the explanation as to why type guarding does not work as expected inside your function:

```
function isNewUserChatEvent2<EventType extends EventTypes>(chatEvent: ChatEvent<EventType>): chatEvent is ChatEvent<'newUser'> {
    return chatEvent.type === 'newUser'
}
```

The above yields:

```
A type predicate's type must be assignable to its parameter's type.
  Type 'ChatEvent<"newUser">' is not assignable to type 'ChatEvent<EventType>'.
    Type '"newUser"' is not assignable to type 'EventType'.
  '"newUser"' is assignable to the constraint of type 'EventType', but 'EventType' could be instantiated with a different subtype of constraint '"incomingMessage" | "newUser"'
```

So because `T extends EvType` constrains `T` to ***any*** implementation of `EvType`, it cannot guarantee the type of `data`.

Curious to see if that enables you to find a better solution!

Comment: Huh, this solution makes me think. It's fine to this simple example (with only two events), but for every new event that I add to the event map, I have to make a new function just to  make the type guard work. Also, this way I can't make a switch statement (`switch (ev.type)`), right?

Comment: I completely agree! I'm not proposing this as a full blown solution. Just wanted to bring up the error it yields that may be explaining why it does not work. To answer your question, no you could not use this in a `switch`.