# How to strongly type an event emitter such that the handler's parameter type is inferred from the event type?

Tags: typescript, generics, typing

I'm trying to define a strongly typed event-emitter, what I mostly want is to have the callback's event type inferred from the string passed to the `addEventHandler` function.

But I've failed so far, and what I came up with infers the event type from the callback, not the opposite.

Here's an example (with a [fiddle](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgHIFcC2AjaBRANwnGQG8BYAKGWTAE8AHCALmQHIMd8jw2BuKjRBZWwrlAGUAvlSqhIsRCgDKYKKADmhYmDKDajFu1XqQWnmH76Azmta3TGyTMpV6TZAEEQdbSQC8aFi4UH66AD7IJpphklQIAPYgtshwACZpYQAScCBpADbQyIEAPHgAKsgQAB6QedZePmEAfAAU7kYVANpsHWwAugA0yAAWuQXQrK2tEBasFQCUxc3IBAnAaQtL-isU1MiJyQmFAHT5CRqtAAbpaRBpVRaj44VQyDAJbwAkpB1SVwtnLJKLdsi9oK0OMFuDo2MMZnMguIwttdvoAPTo2gjYANXEHBLHKhSQHA0EWHJ5V6QzghMJw5AInSsaJmFHLPT7THY-FpBIQawgXoGDwIEYQBAAa2GGkJaWJpNcIIyYKpEN6hmQfIFyBACV0NVxlnh1VYuToqM5NG5AHcRnRdQkRShoFBPgB%20BV8IA)):

```js
interface NumberEvent {
  type: 'NumberEvent';
  num: number;
}

interface StringEvent {
  type: 'StringEvent';
  str: string;
}

type AnyEvent = NumberEvent | StringEvent;

const addEventHandler = <ET extends AnyEvent>(type: ET['type'], handler: ((event: ET) => void)) => {
  console.log(`added event handler for ${type}`);
}

addEventHandler('NumberEvent', (event: NumberEvent) => {
  // this is cool
});

addEventHandler('NumberEvent', (event: StringEvent) => {
  // this doesn't type check, good
});

addEventHandler('type does not exist', (x: any) => {
  // why no type error?
});
```

I do not understand why the last line type-checks, because there is no instance of `AnyEvent` with type `'type does not exist'`.

Can you think of a better approach to the problem?

Comment: Please see [my article](https://catchts.com/publish-subscribe) it should help. Related questions [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65668969/event-maps-and-type-guards#answer-65890181) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70137328/mapping-a-variable-number-of-generics-while-retaining-link-between-type-values#answer-70138046)

Comment: Oh but! I had already started reading your site before, what a small world stackoverflow is! Thanks a lot, I have tons of things to read on my todo list but I'll get there eventually.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve this by making `addEventHandler` generic on the event type, rather than the event object.

```
const addEventHandler = <ET extends AnyEvent['type']>(
  type: ET,
  handler: ((event: Extract<AnyEvent, { type: ET }>) => void)
) => {
  console.log(`added event handler for ${type}`);
}
```

You could also use `AnyEvent & { type: ET }` instead of `Extract<AnyEvent & { type: ET }`

The reason your type doesn't prevent the last case is because `ET` is inferred as `any`. `any["type"]` is still `any`, so it will allow any string at all.

The above version still won't prevent someone from doing this:

```
addEventHandler<any>('type does not exist', (x: any) => {
  // explicitly providing <any>
});
```

You can prevent this, by using the fact that `<anything> & any` is `any`, but personally I wouldn't bother. Nobody is likely to provide `any` here unless intentionally trying to break your types. With the `any` check, you can also go back to your generic:

```
type NotAny<T> = 0 extends (1 & T) ? never : T; 

const addEventHandler = <ET extends AnyEvent>(type: NotAny<ET["type"]>, handler: ((event: ET) => void)) => {
  console.log(`added event handler for ${type}`);
}
```

Comment: Awesome!! Thanks a lot for the solution and for the explanations. I had tried something similar but I must have messed up, I wasn't sure how to perform this "extraction", now I know. And yeah if somebody decides to explicitly pass any... well, there's not much I can do for them at this point, it's their problem.