# Get type of generic's value by key declared on a property in Typescript interface and use it as the type of a function's parameter

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics

I want to add a function signature on a typescript interface which one of its parameters will have a type based on the declared key's value.

I've tried the approach bellow but it doesn't work, as the `value`'s type is every possible type from `T`. Instead, I want the value of the declared key

so if key "num" is a number, I want the "value" parameter in function to be a number

```js
type RowType = Record<string, any>

interface Row<T = RowType, K extends keyof T = keyof T> {
    key: K
    render: (value: T[K], row: T) => any
}

interface DumpRecord = {
    arr: string[], 
    num: number, 
    str: string
}

let row: Row<DumpRecord> = {
 key: 'arr',
 render: (value, row) => ... // value should be array, row should be DumpRecord
}

// or

let row: Row<DumpRecord> = {
 key: 'num',
 render: (value, row) => ... // value should be number
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use [discriminated unions](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/typescript-in-5-minutes-func.html#discriminated-unions) here:

```js
type RowType = Record<string, any>

interface Row<T = RowType, K extends keyof T = keyof T> {
    key: K
    render: (value: T[K], row: T) => any
}

interface DumpRecord {
    arr: string[],
    num: number,
    str: string
}
type Values<T> = T[keyof T]

type Union = Values<{
    [Prop in keyof DumpRecord]: Row<DumpRecord, Prop>
}>

const one: Union = {
    key: 'arr',
    render: (value, row) => {
        value // string[]

    }
}

const two: Union = {
    key: 'num',
    render: (value, row) => {
        value // number
    }
}
```

[Playground](https://tsplay.dev/wjQDMW)

You can find more examples in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65668969/event-maps-and-type-guards#answer-65890181) question and [my article](https://catchts.com/publish-subscribe)